# I can edit other users' contribution with 251 reputation. Is this a defect?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation, editing

I can edit another user's question/answer, but I only have 251 reputation.

Is this a defect or are privledge reputation boundaries different for SE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are the posts community wiki? If so they are editable at a lower rep threshold.

See:

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/privileges
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: Perfect. Will accept this answer in 9 minutes, Thanks for StackOverflow and SE Jeff.